# Why is a powersource characterized by voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, potential, voltage

Why is it that powersources are characterized by their voltage? If we are given a power source with a certain voltage we know that the potential difference per charge will be constant, and it will be that voltage.
Why is it that it is the voltage that is consant?, and not for instance the power or current(I know that these will vary according to Ohms law, but I do not know precisely why it is the voltage that is constant)?

Comment: See Thevanin and Norton equivalent circuits.

Comment: My guess is that it is easier to find a nearly perfect insulator (required to preserve a voltage source) than it is to find a perfect conductor (required to preserve a current source).

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on the context. *Some* power sources are voltage sources, *some* are current sources and *some* are neither. A lead acid car battery when it is fully charged is a pretty good voltage source for almost all loads whose resistance is at least, say, $1\Omega$. It is a very lousy voltage source if you connect to it something of the order $10\rm m\Omega$ or less, don't try it. The collector output of transistor is a pretty good *current* source in the range of say $1-100\rm {mA}$ but you cannot expect to draw much more beyond that. An RF power amplifier is neither a voltage nor a current source for it is impossible to make one at high frequencies at any reasonable efficiency.

What makes the real difference among these sources is the internal resistance (conductance) at the output terminal pair. A lead acid battery has a few milliohm internal resistance, so if you hang on it a $10$ or $100\Omega$ resistor the load's operation will see no difference whether the actual battery resistance is $1\rm m\Omega$ or ten times that as long as the battery is capable to deliver the current. An ideal current source (not a the collector of  transistor) has zero output conductance (infinite internal resistance) and RF power amplifiers are usually designed to have either $50\Omega$ or$75\Omega$ output resistance.

Comment: +1 but I believe the op wants to know why 'most' sources are characterized by a small internal resistance and therefore have an almost horizontal characteristic in the VI plane.

Comment: @Peltio may that is his question but so far he has not commented.

Comment: You say that an ideal currentsource has infinite internal resistance. Does that mean that we have to connect it in parallell and not series as we do with voltage sources?

Comment: @user394334 in the case of a current source, see Norton equivalent, the internal resistance is parallel with the *ideal current source* and then when you hang an impedance on the free terminals the load will be parallel with the internal resistance and the load current *will* depend on the impedance. If you had an ideal current source and you could directly connect to its terminals then any load you connect will have the same current through it.

Comment: @user394334 when you make a Thevenin or Norton equivalent of any source then we usually call one a *voltage* source if in its Thevenin equivalent the source resistance (in general, magnitude of its impedance) is much less than the magnitude of the load impedance attached to the "free" terminals. In contrast, we call one a *current* source if in its Norton equivalent the source resistance (or conductance) (in general, magnitude of its impedance or admittance) is much larger (much smaller) than the magnitude of the load impedance (or admittance) attached to the "free" terminals.

Answer (score 2):

They often are, but there's no reason they can't be characterized by current or power. Constant voltage is more common in engineering for a variety of reasons. A generator spinning at constant speed or a  battery are both examples of practical power sources of nearly constant voltage. A lightly loaded solar panel is approximately constant voltage, but under heavy load, it's approximately constant current.

For circuits containing switchable devices, constant voltage is safer than constant current, since the high voltage needed to drive many loads in series is more dangerous than the high current needed to drive many loads in parallel. For active devices like transistors, the built-in potentials are not influenced much by design, but they may be scaled to low or high current by changing their dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage (difference of electric potentials) supplied by electric power source is a useful datum, because it tells us the likely limit of magnitude of voltage that the powered device will experience when connected to the source.

Electrically powered devices are usually designed to be connected to voltage that falls into some narrow interval, e.g. USB port of a phone expects 5 V $\pm$5%. If the device we want to power is designed to work while connected to voltage of 5 V but not higher, then having the option to quickly check the voltage of the power source is very useful.

Marking power sources by the maximum current they can supply would be possible, but in most practical uses it is not very useful. Maximum current that any such source can provide is very often very undesirable thing to happen, because the current can be made very large by shorting the terminals, and such a large current means lots of heat generated inside the power source as well as the short, and this is outside the desired range of operation.
Lab sources for measurements and experimentation have built-in protection that prevents current from getting too high, and you can even *set* the maximum current they will provide. But these are special expensive devices. Batteries or AC outlet usually do not have such protection and can supply immense currents (until fuse or circuit breaker engage) whose exact maximum value is not interesting because the device is not supposed to consume such a high current.

So the power sources are marked by their voltage, not current because the former is a useful characteristic that makes us prevent harm to connected devices, but the latter is usually useless in practice because maximum current is not the desired mode of operation.